# How to limit items that appear in a form dropdown within a sub form based on the selected value in the main form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, formset

I am in the process of creating a purchase order application but am strugging with limiting the products that a user can select based on a selected supplier.

I have the following models within **models.py**:

```py
class PurchaseOrders(models.Model):
    po_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    po_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Purchase Order Date', auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    supplier_ref = models.ForeignKey(
        Suppliers, verbose_name='Supplier',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    order_net = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Order Net', blank=True, max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2, null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    order_vat = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Order VAT', blank=True, max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2, null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    order_gross = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Order Gross', blank=True, max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2, null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    total_items = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Total Items', blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.po_number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Purchase Orders"


class PoLines(models.Model):
    po_number = models.ForeignKey(
        PurchaseOrders, verbose_name='Purchase Order',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(
        Products, verbose_name='Product',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    supplier_ref = models.ForeignKey(
        Suppliers, verbose_name='Supplier',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    product_movement = models.OneToOneField(
        ProductMovement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Product Price', blank=True, max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2, null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    item_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Item Quantity', blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    item_net = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Item Net', blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    item_vat = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Item VAT', blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    item_gross = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Item Gross', blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_code.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Purchase Order Lines"

class Products(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Product Code', max_length=25, blank=False,
        help_text="This is for the supplier product code for ordering."
        " Please ensure it matches what has been provided by the supplier.")
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Product Name', max_length=100, blank=False)
    shop_location = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Location in Shop', max_length=100, blank=True)
    supplier_ref = models.ForeignKey(
        Suppliers, verbose_name='Supplier',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    last_purchase_price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Last Purchase Price', blank=True, max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2, null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name='Sale Price', blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,
        null=True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    current_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Current Stock Level', blank=True, null=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_code

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

class Suppliers(models.Model):
    payment_type_code = [
        ('Inv', 'Invoice'),
        ('Cash', 'Cash'),
    ]
    discount_type_code = [
        ('None', 'No Discount'),
        ('Val', 'Value'),
        ('Perc', 'Percent'),
    ]
    invoice_type_code = [
        ('Email', 'Email'),
        ('Post', 'Post'),
    ]

    supplier_ref = models.CharField(
        max_length=8, blank=False, help_text="This is for the supplier to"
        " be added to Sage. <strong>Up to 8 characters, only 0-9 and A-Z "
        "allowed.</strong>.")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    supplier_type = models.ForeignKey(
        SupplierType, verbose_name='Supplier Type', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=payment_type_code)
    discount_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, choices=discount_type_code, default='None')
    invoice_type = models.CharField(
        blank=True, max_length=5, choices=invoice_type_code)
    current_balance = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    credit_limit = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    discount_amount = models.DecimalField(
        blank=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    payment_terms = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        blank=True, null=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(90)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Suppliers"
```

There are two forms in my **forms.py** file, one for the overall data for the purchase order and then a modelformset_factory for the individual product lines that appear on the purchase order:

```py
class NewPoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseOrders
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = [
            'po_number',
            'order_net',
            'order_vat',
            'order_gross',
            'total_items',
            ]
        widgets = {
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewPoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-4 col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8 col-lg-7'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Fieldset(
                    '<div class="border-bottom col-md-11 pl-0">'
                    '<h5>Purchase Order Details</h5></div>',
                    'supplier_ref',
                ),
                css_class="col-md-6"
            ),
        )


po_line_formset = modelformset_factory(
    PoLines,
    fields=(
        'product_code',
        'product_price',
        'item_quantity',
        ),
    extra=1
)
```

My **views.py** file is as follows:

```py
def new_po(request):
    if PurchaseOrders.objects.all().exists():
        next_po = PurchaseOrders.objects.last().po_number
    else:
        next_po = 0
    template_name = 'purchase_orders/new_po.html'
    title_message = 'New Purchase Order'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        poForm = NewPoForm(prefix='purchase_orders')
        formset = po_line_formset(queryset=POLines.objects.none())
        helper = LineHelper()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        poForm = NewPOForm(request.POST, prefix='purchase_orders')
        formset = POLineFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid() and poForm.is_valid():
            print('DATA IS CORRECT')
            po = po_form_save(poForm, formset)
            formset_save(formset, po)
            messages.success(request, f"Purchase Order Successfully added.")
            # once all items are saved, redirect to list view
            return redirect('purchase_orders')
    return render(request, template_name, {
        'poForm': poForm,
        'formset': formset,
        'helper': helper,
        'title': title_message,
        'date': date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'next_po': next_po + 1,
    })
```

I have the main process working where the purchase order can be created and this validates and will save to the database with the relevant product lines. But currently it is allowing any product to be selected within the **po_line_formset** instead of limiting the options to the selected supplier from the main **NewPoForm**.

Is there a way to do this dynamically based on the selected supplier?

Comment: Based on the title of your question, one option is to use ajax. You need to send the choice in the first form to the server and get the query_set to fill the choices of the second form. Or you have to send both forms choices in one server request and use front end technologies to load the second form filetered choices based on the first form

Comment: @AminBa thanks for the above, I actually was in the process of going down the ajax route and now have it working, thanks once again.

Comment: Your welcome. I actually have the same problem as you do. I am currently creating an mvp. When I reached to point that I wanted to pre-occupy the form fields based on what is inserted in another field, I will use your solution. So pease share it in here

Comment: @AminBa, this link helped get the files set up correctly, i had to make a number of changes due to using formsets but it should hopefully give you a starting point. [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)